# I have some error with my code, can someone please review it once

Tags: python, encryption, jupyter-notebook, rsa, public-key-encryption

[[https://github.com/Simrantiwarii/RSA-ENCYRPTION/blob/1e88b32c9d1e133886f73115374d5018d946f5b8/Untitled6.ipynb]](https://github.com/Simrantiwarii/RSA-ENCYRPTION/blob/1e88b32c9d1e133886f73115374d5018d946f5b8/Untitled6.ipynb)
Can someone please look into this code and tell me why is it giving this error:

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-43-01ba3f5a9a3e> in <module>
>      88 
>      89 if __name__ == '__main__':
> ---> 90     public_key,private_key = generate_keyPairs()
>      91     print("Public: ",public_key)
>      92     print("Private: ",private_key)
>
> <ipython-input-43-01ba3f5a9a3e> in generate_keyPairs()
>      53         E = generatenextPrime(E)
>      54         #print(type(F))
> ---> 55         g = gcd(E,phi)
>      56     #print("E=",E,)
>      57     #print(type(E))
>
> <ipython-input-43-01ba3f5a9a3e> in gcd(a, b)
>      11 def gcd(a, b):
>      12     while b != 0:
> ---> 13         a, b = b, a % b
>      14     return a
>      15 
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

I am trying to study the nature of encryption key component 'e' in RSA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error message says: a is not a number but None. I assume that `generatenextPrime(E)` returns None

```
def generatenextPrime(num):
    E = num+1
    #print ("E= %d" %E)
    if is_prime(E):
        return E
    else:
        num += 1  # <--- nothing (None) is returned in that case
```

try this instead

```
def generatenextPrime(num):
    e = num
    while not is_prime(e):
        e += 1
    return e
```

Comment: Can you please review my code, and tell me what should I change in generatenextPrime(E) function, so that it gives the next prime number to E?

Comment: generatenextPrime is not included in your question

Comment: [https://github.com/Simrantiwarii/RSA-ENCYRPTION/blob/1e88b32c9d1e133886f73115374d5018d946f5b8/Untitled6.ipynb] this is my code

Comment: ^ I updated the answer :)

Comment: Can you help me out, and tell me what exactly I need to change so that `generatenextPrime` returns into the the same incrementing loop and returns a prime number instead of NONE.

Comment: what you probably want to do is incrementing num in a while loop until is_prime(E) returns true.

Comment: yess. I want the same

Comment: ^ I added such a version to the answer

Comment: Thanks, it worked..